# GitHub account unavailable on Xcode 10.2

Tags: xcode, preferences, accounts

I noticed a strange behaviour in my Xcode (v10.2, running on a 2016 MacBook Pro with macOS 10.14.4). I have most of my projects under source control with a local Git repository. I then create a remote to GitHub via Xcode and commit and push from the source control menu.

Since yesterday every time I committed I got asked for my username and password. At first I thought it was something normal due to some connectivity issue but then the issue persisted and, going to Xcode Preferences > accounts I noticed that my GitHub account was greyed out and, upon selecting it (or trying to) the right side of the window showed this message:

Account Unavailable Your account details could not be loaded because Accountname support is currently unavailable

At this point it is impossible to remove my GitHub account from Xcode in order to add it once more and it is also impossible to add any source control account, as if something with version control in general would be very broken. I thought it an issue with my SSH key for GitHub so I went on and scrapped the old one and generated a new one. The account stayed on "Loading" for a good minute and then the same message presented itself once more.

I really have no idea what to do here.

What is causing this and how do I get out of it?

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a tough one to search for but I did find this SO Q&A titled: [Xcode source control wrong username on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529737/xcode-source-control-wrong-username-on-github)
. There's an answer there that shows the use of a CLI tool called `xcrun` to manipulate your Github credentials that are stored in Xcode, for eg:

```
$ xcrun git config --local user.name 'new_user_name'
$ xcrun git config --local user.email 'new@email.com'
```

Might help with getting your issue sorted out.

#### Xcode 10

I was also able to find reports of people having the same issue as you where their source repos (Bitbucket, Github, etc) were greyed out in Xcode. For eg:

[image: ss1]

This reddit thread titled: [Add GitHub account greyed out on Xcode 10, can't fix](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/aexve5/add_github_account_greyed_out_on_xcode_10_cant_fix/) mentions this process for manually deleting out the creds. This appears to be a issue with Xcode 10 itself.

> Happened to me, this is the only thing that worked (from StackOverflow):
>
> - Make screenshots of the custom preference settings
> - Delete `/Applications/Xcode`
> - Delete all files containing `com.apple.dt`
>     in `~/Library/Caches`
> - Delete all files containing `com.apple.dt`
>     in `~/Library/Preferences`
> - Open `App Store.app`, download and re-install Xcode.
> - Create the Apple ID developer account
>
> After those steps all account types were enabled and I could create the GitHub account. Finally restore your custom preference settings from the screenshots.

#### References

- [Xcode add Github account not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363656/xcode-add-github-account-not-possible/52383600)

Comment: Thank you, I already tried that and it didn’t work

Comment: @NeeratheWildMage - Do you mind posting a screen shot of Xcode - 'Xcode-> Preferences-> Accounts. Under "Source Control Accounts"'? I'm .curious if you have the -/+ buttons there to add/remove accounts directly through Xcode.

Comment: I have the two buttons there but then only Apple ID and Xcode Server are available, everything else is greyed out and marked (unavailable). So not just GitHub, also Bitbucket. I wonder if in Mojave I have to give extra permissions or what...

Comment: @NeeratheWildMage - if that doesn't work I found this which seems to indicate that creds might be stored in keychain - https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain.

Comment: GitHub support told me the same thing. Removing those two keys did absolutely nothing... :-( don’t know what to do anymore...

Comment: From CLI can you interact w/ github?

Comment: I’m not very comfortable with command line but the incredible thing is: I created a new project today with Git repository, the blue line is showing even without the account connected and from the GitHub desktop app I can manage all the committing so, if I had never used Xcode for that I would have probably never noticed it...

Comment: @NeeratheWildMage - I'd chk your SSH keys to start - `ssh -T git@github.com` - https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection.

Comment: I followed the steps and got to where it said hello username you are successfully authenticated. Lunching Xcode doesn’t show any progress though...

Comment: @NeeratheWildMage - this describes how to manually clear out the creds for Xcode - https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/aexve5/add_github_account_greyed_out_on_xcode_10_cant_fix/.

Comment: So actually delete those files and reinstall? Ok, will do and report back in a few hours. Where can non-registered Developer download the Xcode installer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92194/discussion-between-slm-and-neera-the-wild-mage).

Comment: I tried with everything and at last reinstalling, Xcode works for me. I would say just re-install it again to get it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in Xcode. After updating to Xcode 10.2.1 the "push to remote" checkbox was suddenly greyed out with all my projects. I tried several of the solutions I found online, for example deleting and re-adding all the keychain GitHub entries as well as reinstalling Xcode, but nothing worked.

I believe this is a problem with this version of Xcode and until it is fixed, I found this workaround which allowed me to update my projects on the remote GitHub through the Xcode SourceControl tab as usual. 
 
First, I removed my existing remote repositories from GitHub and added new empty repositories. Then, I deleted all my local git repositories. Once that was done, I opened terminal and went back into my project's folder and ran the following commands. 
`$ git init`
`$ git commit -m "Initial Github Recommit"`
`$ git remote add origin https://github.com/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>.git` 

Then, I opened my Xcode project >SourceControl>Commit... and the push to remote checkbox was no longer greyed out and functioned properly.

This worked for me and I hope it is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested fixes didn't work for me. I ended up updating to 11.
It has a bug number: 47645098.  Apple's official answer "is it's fixed in 11". Thanks for the info on how to correct it. Having to move to 11 to get an official fix is iffy at best.

From Xcode 11 Release notes:

> Resolved issues where hosted account providers like GitHub and
>   BitBucket were unavailable in the add account sheet, and previously
>   added accounts would be disabled. (47645098)